# Для чего может быть нужна переменная абстрактного класса?

Tags: c#

Я знаю, что объект абстрактного класса нельзя создать, но можно объявить переменную абстрактного класса. Поясните на примере, пожалуйста, зачем может быть нужна переменная абстрактного класса.

Comment: Потому что в нее можно поместить ссылку на экземпляр любого класса-наследника

Comment: Поясните еще, пожалуйста, зачем могут понадобиться простые поля в абстрактном классе, т.е. не в виде свойств

Comment: Как один из вариантов: если классу нужна некоторая зависимость, например, логгер, но ему всё равно какой это будет логгер (пишущий в файл или в БД или отправляющий логи на почту), то вы объявляете в классе поле `private readonly abstractLogger;`, а сам экземпляр логгера получаете через конструктор и записываете в это поле. Затем везде в коде класса просто используете этот экземпляр для логгирования.

Comment: Абстрактный класс может выполнять такую роль что и обычный базовый при наследование. За исключением лишь что вам нельзя будет создать его экземпляр. Иными словами это может вам понадобится для реализации общего поведения и параметров, но как самостоятельным экземпляром такой класс являться не будет.

Comment: @АндрейNOP почему бы для этих целей не пользоваться интерфейсами. Просто интересно, в каких случаях использование переменных, указывающих на абстрактный класс, предпочтительнее чем переменные, указывающие на интерфейс?

Comment: @tym32167, можно и интерфейсами. Тут скорее чисто семантическая разница, впрочем, я не профессионал, просто ответил на вопрос ТС.

Comment: @АндрейNOP `я не профессионал` сказал юзер с 16к репутацией :D

Comment: Для того чтобы иметь некоторый уровень абстракции при работе с объектами классов-наследников если блоку неважно знать с каким именно наследником он имеет дело.

Comment: @tym32167, ну это чистая правда. Вы не хуже меня знаете, что уровень репутации зависит только от лени и количества свободного времени :)

Answer (score 6):

Кроме обычных классов в C# есть абстрактные классы. Абстрактный класс похож на обычный класс. Он также может иметь переменные, методы, конструкторы, свойства. Единственное, что при определении абстрактных классов используется ключевое слово abstract:

```
abstract class Human
{
    public int Length { get; set; }
    public double Weight { get; set; }
}
```

Но главное отличие состоит в том, что мы не можем использовать конструктор абстрактного класса для создания его объекта. Например, следующим образом:

```
Human h = new Human();
```

Зачем нужны абстрактные классы? Допустим, в нашей программе для банковского сектора мы можем определить две основных сущности: клиента банка и сотрудника банка. Каждая из этих сущностей будет отличаться, например, для сотрудника надо определить его должность, а для клиента - сумму на счете. Соответственно клиент и сотрудник будут составлять отдельные классы Client и Employee. В то же время обе этих сущности могут иметь что-то общее, например, имя и фамилию, какую-то другую общую функциональность. И эту общую функциональность лучше вынести в какой-то отдельный класс, например, Person, который описывает человека. То есть классы Employee (сотрудник) и Client (клиент банка) будут производными от класса Person. И так как все объекты в нашей системе будут представлять либо сотрудника банка, либо клиента, то напрямую мы от класса Person создавать объекты не будем. Поэтому имеет смысл сделать его абстрактным:

```
abstract class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public Person(string name, string surname)
    {
        FirstName = name;
        LastName = surname;
    }

    public void Display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(FirstName + " " + LastName);
    }
}

class Client : Person
{
    public int Sum { get; set; }    // сумма на счету

    public Client(string name, string surname, int sum)
        : base(name, surname)
    {
        Sum = sum;
    }
}

class Employee : Person
{
    public string Position { get; set; } // должность

    public Employee(string name, string surname, string position) 
        : base(name, surname)
    {
            Position = position;
    }
}
```

Затем мы сможем использовать эти классы:

```
Client client = new Client("Tom", "Smith", 500);
Employee employee = new Employee ("Bob", "Tompson", "Apple");
client.Display();
employee.Display();
```

Или даже так:

```
Person client = new Client("Tom", "Smith", 500);
Person employee = new Employee ("Bob", "Tompson", "Операционист");
```

Но мы НЕ можем создать объект Person, используя конструктор класса Person:

```
Person person = new Person ("Bill", "Gates");
```

Однако несмотря на то, что напрямую мы не можем вызвать конструктор класса Person для создания объекта, тем не менее конструктор в абстрактных классах то же может играть важную роль. В частности, в классе Person конструктор инициализирует свойства FirstName и LastName. И хотя напрямую он не вызывается, тем не менее производные классы Client и Employee могут обращаться к нему.

> Абстрактные члены классов

Кроме обычных свойств и методов абстрактный класс может иметь абстрактные методы и свойства. Подобные методы и свойства определяются с помощью ключевого слова abstract и не имеют никакого функционала. Кроме того, они не должны иметь модификатор private.

При этом производный класс обязан переопределить и реализовать все абстрактные методы и свойства, которые имеются в базовом абстрактном классе. При переопределении в производном классе такой метод или свойство также объявляются с модификатором override (как и при обычно переопределении виртуальных методов и свойств). Также следует учесть, что если класс имеет хотя бы одно абстрактное свойство или метод, то он должен быть определен как абстрактный. Например, сделаем в примере выше метод Display абстрактным:

```
abstract class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public Person(string name, string surname)
    {
        FirstName = name;
        LastName = surname;
    }

    public abstract void Display();
}

class Client : Person
{
    public int Sum { get; set; }    // сумма на счету

    public Client(string name, string surname, int sum)
        : base(name, surname)
    {
        Sum = sum;
    }
    public override void Display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{FirstName} {LastName} имеет счет на сумму {Sum}");
    }
}

class Employee : Person
{
    public string Position { get; set; } // должность

    public Employee(string name, string surname, string position) 
        : base(name, surname)
    {
        Position = position;
    }

    public override void Display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{Position} {FirstName} {LastName}");
    }
}
```

Абстрактные методы также, как и виртуальные, являются частью полиморфного интерфейса. Но если в случае с виртуальными методами мы говорим, что класс-наследник наследует реализацию, то в случае с абстрактными методами наследуется интерфейс, представленный этими абстрактными методами.

Другим хрестоматийным примером является система геометрических фигур. В реальности не существует геометрической фигуры как таковой. Есть круг, прямоугольник, квадрат, но просто фигуры нет. Однако же и круг, и прямоугольник имеют что-то общее и являются фигурами:

```
// абстрактный класс фигуры
abstract class Figure
{
    // абстрактный метод для получения периметра
    public abstract float Perimeter();
    // абстрактный метод для получения площади
    public abstract float Area();
}
// производный класс прямоугольника
class Rectangle : Figure
{
    public float Width { get; set; }
    public float Height { get; set; }

    public Rectangle(float width, float height)
    {
        this.Width = width;
        this.Height = height;
    }
    // переопределение получения периметра
    public override float Perimeter()
    {
        return Width * 2 + Height * 2;
    }
    // переопрелеление получения площади
    public override float Area()
    {
        return Width * Height;
    }
}
```

Comment: вы ответили на всё, кроме главного вопроса - `Для чего может быть нужна переменная абстрактного класса?`

Comment: Столько всего написали и почти весь текст мимо кассы

Comment: Вам правда не понятно из этих строк Person client = new Client("Tom", "Smith", 500);
Person employee = new Employee ("Bob", "Tompson", "Операционист");  зачем нужны переменные? @yolosora

Comment: @TEA я и не сказал, что всё мимо кассы. Просто сначала нужно прочитать огромное интро об абстрактных классах, которое довольно косвенно относится к поставленному вопросу и уже в глубине текста найти ответ на поставленный вопрос

Comment: @TEA то есть в целом ваш ответ больше подходит под вопрос "Зачем нужны абстрактные классы", а не под этот довольно узко заданный вопрос

Comment: Возможно имеет смысл вынести точный ответ в блок вида TLDR:, а это произведение оставить в виде расширенного варианта